# How do I get JRE 7.6 to eclipse on my mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

So I needed to get Java-to-Javascript communication. After some research I was told to download JRE 7.6. Now that I have done so, how do I get eclipse to see the updated JRE?
When I go to `Eclipse >> Preferences >> Java >> Installed JREs`, I see version `1.7.0_21`.

All of this is so that I can get the following import to work again: I moved my project from linux:

```
import netscape.javascript.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do to get the JRE into eclipse was hit the search button. So basically this answers that question.